# Intersection of 2 lines in 2D via General Form Linear Equations

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

). Recently, I asked you how to find the "Intersection of 2 Lines in 2D" and the answers revolved around the Determinants ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection ) or Systems ( [Intersection Of Two Lines In 2D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25171/intersection-of-two-lines-in-2d/25173#25173) ).

Now, based on what I learned here from Isaac about how to get the General Form Linear Equation from 2 points ( [How to obtain equation of line of the form $ax + by + c = 0$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/25190/how-to-obtain-line-equation-of-the-form-ax-bx-c-0) ), isn't it simpler to find the intersection like this?

Where x1 to x4 and y1 to y4 are the 4 points defining the 2 lines.

```
  //First line's Equation.
  var a: Number = y1 - y2;
  var b: Number = x2 - x1;
  var c: Number = (y2 - y1) * x1 - (x2 - x1) * y1;

  //Second line's Equation.
  var d: Number = y3 - y4;
  var e: Number = x4 - x3;
  var f: Number = (y4 - y3) * x3 - (x4 - x3) * y3;

  //Below formulas obtained via System.
  intersection.y = (c*d - f*a) / (-d*b + a*e);
  intersection.x = (-b * intersection.y - c) / a;
```

It seems to me to be less mathematical operations here compared to the determinants solution. Does this method seem ok to you, mathematically speaking? I like that it's slope-independent (vertical lines result in useless checks in those cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `ret.y` is `intersection.y`, your results look good to me.  If you want to make sure that you are safe for all lines, you probably should change the `intersection.x` formula so that it doesn't depend on `a` being nonzero: $$x=\frac{bf-ce}{-db+ae}$$ (If $-db+ae=0$, which both $x$ and $y$ have in the denominator, the two lines do not intersect.)

These formulae for $x$ and $y$ in terms of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$ are equivalent to applying [Cramer's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Explicit_formulas_for_small_systems) (beware that the use of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, and $f$ there are not quite the same), which uses determinants.

Comment: Hi Isaac! ::- D. Ouch, I forgot to modify that 'ret' to 'intersection'. You are correct (I just found out the hard way), my solution depends on `a` and `b` being non-zero so I think I'm going to use the determinants after all. Thank you for bringing this case up ::- D.

Comment: Third time you're helping me out. Thank you VERY much ::- D. I learned a lot from you and the others here. 2 weeks ago I wouldn't have been able to come up even with such a broken solution like I did now ::- D.

Comment: @Axonn: You're welcome.  And I wouldn't have called this a broken solution at all.  Other than the case where $a=0$, it works just fine, and it's a relatively minor change to correct for that.